# If frequency of light never changes, is there finite number of blue light, red light, etc.?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, frequency, wavelength

AFAIK light's frequency cannot change. If that is the case, would it mean that there is a finite amount of every frequency floating around in the universe? ie. some finite number of 400hz light rays, 500hz 600hz, etc?

Perhaps this is a strange follow up, but would it be possible to have an apple in a room with me, but not be able to see it due to there being no red light in the room?

Comment: Light's frequency can change due to a variety of effects, including Doppler effect and gravitational redshift.

Comment: @DanDan0101 Yeah I've heard of that, but those don't actually change the frequency of the light, right? they only change how we perceive the frequency.

Comment: Compton scattering already makes your first statement incorrect, light has a different frequency before and after the collision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would it mean that there is a finite amount of every frequency floating around in the universe?

Well, if the universe is finite, then there is certainly a finite amount of photons.  But I think you mean is there a constant amount.  If so, that's not true because light and other forms of EM radiation are constantly being created and absorbed in various interactions.

Further, the frequency of light is frame-dependent.  Different viewers will not agree on the frequency, so any sort of attempt to sum them would be difficult even if it could be enumerated.